# I am using auth function in laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I have two models users and user_profiles

```
user

id name email

user_prfiles

id user_id fname lname address
```

this is a one to one relation concept, my doubt is, I add user_profiles details in my table and user table is also good but again the same person login he can view the link of create details which will create user_profiles details of particular user. and my point is when a user fill all of his user profile
the link should not display how can I do that? how to hide the link once the data created? if anyone knows please share the answer..

Comment: You need to define the percentage for each field. On every filed filled up percentage of data complete will increase. Once it will reach 100 then when the user will come for second time you can validate the link from the profile completed percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

## Code

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function userProfile()
    {
        $this->hasOne('App\UserProfile');
    }
}

class UserProfile extends Model
{
    isComplete()
    {
        // check if all fields is what you expect
    }
}
```

## In your view

```
<h1>User dashboard</h1>
@if(!$user->userProfile || !$user->userProfile->isComplete())
    <a href="user-profiles/123/edit">Fill in your profile</a>
@endif
```

Comment: if you dont mind can you please tell me exactly what should I do inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the answer, in my create page

```
@if(!Auth::user()->userprofile)
   <form>
   </form>
   @else
   <div>already created</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Trying to get property 'userprofile' of non-object (View: E:\Xampp\htdocs\Projects\laravel\Interview\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
```

I get this error when I did as you say..

```
@if(!Auth::user()->userprofile || !Auth::user()->userprofile->isComplete())                          
   <a class="nav-link active text-dark" href="/users/create">Add Details</a>
@endif
```

this is my app.blade.php

my UserProfile.php

```
public function isComplete()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class);
}
```